# Is there a way to launch a program that it sees the current windows search result as its working directory?

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer, windows-search

Let's say I have a bunch of files in various formats, and my default media player/image viewer/comic reader/text editor/etc would normally grab all the relevant files in the current folder and add them to a playlist/project/etc. I would like to ad hoc slim that list down via windows search. Is there an easy way to have whatever program gets launched see the current search results, rather than the whole folder, as if it were the current working directory? I'm still on 10.

Comment: I doubt it, but it would in any case depend on which player you use. You may want to add that information to your question

Comment: How are these programs even aware of a "current directory"in Explorer? Are they launched from a context menu?

Comment: Just copy all (Ctrl-A, Ctrl-C) in the search results, right-click list and use *Send To* context menu  item to forward them to an app that takes multiple arguments, e.g., VLC.

Comment: Hello, this question would make sense for a specific program. But right now you're asking "Is there a way to make my car drive faster?" type of question, basically.